# Запись данных в Realm

Tags: java, android, realm-database

Читаю тьюториал по Realm и возник такой вопрос, по поводу записи данных в БД, есть такой код, является ли строчка `User user = realm.createObject(User.class);` к тому, что данные сохраняются в БД? или это просто создание объекта и еще отдельно нужно сохранять данные?

```
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    User user = realm.createObject(User.class);
                    realm.cancelTransaction();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это просто создание объекта, чтобы записать используйте `insertOrUpdate(T item)` или `copyOrUpdate(T item)`;